# Como eliminar en javascript un elemento específico que tengan una clase

Tags: javascript, clase

Yo tengo el botón:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger sc-cart-clear" onclick="return del()" type="button" />
```

y la función:

`function del() {a = $('#contInloock'); $('.TheLessWanted').remove();}`

Esto me borra todos los elementos de la clase `.TheLessWanted`

los elementos los tengo dentro de un div en un input dinamico

> Como yo puedo borrar un elemento específico de esa clase?

Comment: Necesitaras de alguna forma que tenga algo que lo diferencie de los demas, si no es imposible.

Comment: Ignacio,. nos puedes pegar más objetos de esa clase para hacerte un ejemplo?

Answer (score 2):

> Dependiendo de si filtras una clase, un ID, un atributo, etc.  se hace
>   de diferentes modos. Debes repasar la documentación de [Selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_CSS)

Espero que este ejemplo te valga.

```js
function delTodos() {a = $('#contInloock'); $('.TheLessWanted').remove();}

function del() {a = $('#contInloock'); $('#boton1.TheLessWanted').remove();}

function del2() {a = $('#contInloock'); $('#boton2.TheLessWanted').remove();}

function del3() {a = $('#contInloock'); $('#boton3.TheLessWanted.tres').remove();}

function del4() {a = $('#contInloock'); $('#boton3.TheLessWanted.cuatro').remove();}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-danger sc-cart-clear" onclick="return delTodos()" type="button" />TODOS</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger sc-cart-clear" onclick="return del()" type="button" />UNO</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger sc-cart-clear" onclick="return del2()" type="button" />DOS</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger sc-cart-clear" onclick="return del3()" type="button" />TRES</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger sc-cart-clear" onclick="return del4()" type="button" />CUATRO</button>

<br>

<a class="TheLessWanted" id="boton1">uno</a>
<br>
<a class="TheLessWanted" id="boton2">Dos</a>
<br>
<a class="TheLessWanted tres" id="boton3">Tres</a>
<br>
<a class="TheLessWanted cuatro" id="boton3">Cuatro</a>
```